# Vue separate brand with starting letter

Tags: vuejs2

This is the result that i want, want it to separate into group with starting letter

[image]

Here is the data

```
{
     { "id": "61", "name": "1028 Visual Therapy", "slug": "1028-visual-therapy", "__typename": "Brand" }
     { "id": "51", "name": "3W Clinic", "slug": "3w-clinic", "__typename": "Brand" }
     { "id": "128", "name": "A. By BOM", "slug": "a-by-bom", "__typename": "Brand" }
     { "id": "96", "name": "ACTIMED", "slug": "actimed", "__typename": "Brand" }
     { "id": "123", "name": "Always be Pure", "slug": "always-be-pure", "__typename": "Brand" }
     { "id": "28", "name": "AMPM", "slug": "ampm", "__typename": "Brand" }
     { "id": "3", "name": "Angel Key", "slug": "angel-key", "__typename": "Brand" }
     { "id": "99", "name": "Annie's Way", "slug": "annies-way", "__typename": "Brand" }
     { "id": "67", "name": "APRIL SKIN", "slug": "april-skin", "__typename": "Brand" }
     { "id": "126", "name": "Aurora D.", "slug": "aurora-d", "__typename": "Brand" }
     { "id": "124", "name": "AXIS-Y", "slug": "axis-y", "__typename": "Brand" }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a computed to sort/group the items however you want:

```js
Vue.component("SingleItem", {
  props: ['item'],
  template: `
    <div
      class="single-item"
    >
      {{ item.name }}
    </div>
  `
})
Vue.component("ItemGroup", {
  props: ['group', 'char'],
  template: `
    <div>
      <strong>{{ char }}</strong><br />
      <div
        class="d-grid"
      >
        <single-item
          v-for="item in group"
          :item="item"
        ></single-item>
      </div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          "id": "61",
          "name": "1028 Visual Therapy",
          "slug": "1028-visual-therapy",
          "__typename": "Brand"
        },
        {
          "id": "51",
          "name": "3W Clinic",
          "slug": "3w-clinic",
          "__typename": "Brand"
        },
        {
          "id": "128",
          "name": "A. By BOM",
          "slug": "a-by-bom",
          "__typename": "Brand"
        },
        {
          "id": "96",
          "name": "ACTIMED",
          "slug": "actimed",
          "__typename": "Brand"
        },
        {
          "id": "123",
          "name": "Always be Pure",
          "slug": "always-be-pure",
          "__typename": "Brand"
        },
        {
          "id": "28",
          "name": "AMPM",
          "slug": "ampm",
          "__typename": "Brand"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "Angel Key",
          "slug": "angel-key",
          "__typename": "Brand"
        },
        {
          "id": "99",
          "name": "Annie's Way",
          "slug": "annies-way",
          "__typename": "Brand"
        },
        {
          "id": "67",
          "name": "APRIL SKIN",
          "slug": "april-skin",
          "__typename": "Brand"
        },
        {
          "id": "126",
          "name": "Aurora D.",
          "slug": "aurora-d",
          "__typename": "Brand"
        },
        {
          "id": "124",
          "name": "AXIS-Y",
          "slug": "axis-y",
          "__typename": "Brand"
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    itemsGroupedByFirstChar() {
      return this.items.reduce((a, c) => {
        if (typeof a[c.name.charAt(0)] === "undefined") a[c.name.charAt(0)] = []
        a[c.name.charAt(0)].push(c)
        return a
      }, {})
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <item-group
        v-for="(val, key, i) in itemsGroupedByFirstChar"
        :key="'group-'+ key + '-' + i"
        :group="val"
        :char="key"
      ></item-group>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```css
.d-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.single-item {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```